# How to fish electric wire from one end to other end of a long pipe

Tags: electricity

I have a couple of narrow pipes and couple of bent pipes in my home. I want to bring electric wires from one end to other end. I need simple, cheap & quickest ways to do that.

Answer (score 15):

The best solution is to use the tool designed for the task: a 'fish tape' or wire puller. This is a flexible tape or wire designed to be pushed through electrical conduits. Push the tape through, hook your electrical wires to the tape, and pull the tape back, dragging the electrical wires along.

In a pinch, you can try this (works only if your conduit has no wiring boxes or branches):

1. Find an old audio cassette you don't mind destroying.
2. Pull the tape from the cassette.
3. Get a vacuum cleaner, put its nozzle on one end of the conduit.
4. Thread the tape into the other end, and let the vacuum cleaner pull it through.
5. Attach a fishing line or other thin thread to the tape.
6. Pull that through.
7. Attach a thicker line to the thin line and pull that through.
8. Use the thicker line to pull the electrical wires through.

Comment: If pulling the wire as described above is difficult, you can also purchase lube made for the task or use a bit of dishwashing detergent on a towel and held against the insulation on the wire to help it slide along the conduit.